How to center title in PDF Export in Balkan OrgChartJS
function preview() {
    /*centerElement();*/
    let fileNameWithTitle = MyTitle.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
    let PdfTitle = "<center>" + MyTitle + "</center>";
    OrgChart.pdfPrevUI.show(chart, {
        format: 'A4',
        landscape: true,
        padding: 50,
        header: PdfTitle,
        filename: fileNameWithTitle += "_OrgChart.pdf"
    });
}

Above are the code that I use to preview the pdf first before exporting. I've tried to center the element by hardcoding the  tag into the title itself but it does not work because the header are actually in a  tag like below:
<div id="boc-header" style="color: rgb(117, 117, 117); position: absolute; left: 40px; top: -15px;"><h3 style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-item: center;">Division Organization Chart</h3></div>

Targeting the  with id boc-header wont also work, as it only center in the website, but when exporting itself(occur at balkan server) the result will always be the title place at left side.
In case you wondering how I target the id boc-header,
<style id="myStyles">
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gochi+Hand");

    .node {
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    boc-header {
        color: rgb(117, 117, 117) !important;
        position: absolute !important;
        left: 50% !important;
        top: 15px !important;
        transform: translateX(-50%) !important;
    }

    .node.HR rect {
        fill: #E99113;
    }
    .node.HR line {
        stroke: #E99113;
    }
</style>

chart.on('exportstart', function (sender, args) {
    args.styles += document.getElementById('myStyles').outerHTML;
});


I am not sure if this is possible. The only way to center it is by manipulating the title. As whatever stye I apply it, it follows in the exported result.
Thank you.
All detail are above

Here is a code example:
https://code.balkan.app/org-chart-js/center-header-on-pdf-export#HTML
<!--HTML-->
<script src="https://balkan.app/js/OrgChart.js"></script>
<style id="myStyles">#boc-header, #bg-header {text-align: center;}</style>
<div id="tree"/>
 

Here is the result:


Where do you get the id #bg-header? In the page when I was inspecting there is no element with id bg-header. It seems there only exist the boc-header in the page, and that was to control it looks before exporting

It is in the export service: https://github.com/BALKANGraph/export-service/blob/master/export3.js
